# High CPU load after massive delete on PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I've deleted ~65 million rows from a PostgreSQL table with ~75 million rows.
As soon as the deletion query completed, the CPU plummeted to 100% for about five minutes.

The table from which rows were deleted has multiple indexes and was in heavy use during the deletion and after it. Unfortunately I don't have a way to reproduce this, since it happened on production environment.

Is it likely that the autovacuum kicked in and if so, could it drive a database with 32 CPU cores to 100% CPU usage? If so, is there a way to limit the intake of autovacuum so it doesn't degrade the database performance after massive delete queries?

I'm using PostgreSQL version 14.8.

Comment: "*so it doesn't degrade the database performance after massive delete queries?*" - How often do you plan on deleting 65 million rows at a time?

Comment: I will certainly make it so that it doesn't happen automatically. Mainly, I intend to understand the behavior, so I know what to avoid / expect.

Comment: all the indexes need to be updated, that will take time. Can You delet the rows in smaller batches, so that the time consumed. Also it is usual to run such queries at a time, where the load is much lower for example night time shift changes

Comment: Guess I'd do deletion in batches from now on. I just didn't expect it to drive the CPU to 100% - was hoping PostgreSQL would have some sort throttling mechanics to block background jobs from driving the CPU to 100%.

Comment: @AlexGordon "*...some sort throttling mechanics to block background jobs from driving the CPU to 100%.*" - Why wouldn't you want to use the entirety of the hardware resources you're paying for already? The way a database system is designed is for the purpose of having its own server (not to share its resources with other systems) because of the typical critical importance of performance at that layer. If you meant, you were hoping it balances how it utilizes those resources internally, then yes it does even under high load, but the total consumption from internal processes will still = 100%.

Comment: Essentially, it's a waste of money if you're not *mostly* utilizing your hardware resources on a database server, and they're just sitting idle.

Comment: I see your point, consider however that for a database that supports a web service which is optimized for performance, reaching 100% CPU almost always implies a serious degradation in response time - which might not be acceptable by some SLAs. I understand the approach of use 'em while you got 'em, but wish there was some way to reserve CPU for queries. That would essentially come with it's own dangers, like starving autovacuum tasks etc..

Comment: @AlexGordon "*but wish there was some way to reserve CPU for queries.*" - I think you missed this part of my comment: "*If you meant, you were hoping it balances how it utilizes those resources internally, then yes it does even under high load, but the total consumption from internal processes will still = 100%.*". So again, yes for internal processes / queries, it manages the load. It's not perfect though, and to your point, some queries are higher priority, so that's why *how* a query is designed is important, such as batching large deletes. There's other ways to prioritize queries also.

Comment: So I guess that due to the deletion of 65 million rows, the autovacuum and updating indexes, along with the ongoing queries to the DB which had the CPU at ~50%, drove it from 50% to 100%, and that's quite normal, even for a database with 32 cores.

I'll look into options that allow controlling this to some extent.

Comment: If this is a routine thing, I'd recommend partitioning the table.  Detach the partition you no longer need, and then drop it when you are ready to drop it.  Much, much faster and easier than trying to rip a bunch of rows out of a big table.

Comment: It's aggregated work due to a worker that was offline for a while. Generally it shouldn't be such a heavy deletion. I was mainly curios as to what could have caused me these 5 minutes of stress :) But thanks for the tip - would keep that in mind.

Comment: 65 million, 75 million, 100%, that's not nearly enough information to understand what was really going on. Autovacuum did kick in, that's for sure, but's unlikely that it used 16 cores for that. And cleaning up is usually more IO intensive then it is CPU intensive.

Comment: @AlexGordon Btw, Partitioning is one example of what I meant by "*There's other ways to prioritize queries also.*", I just ran out of comment room lol. But yea database and query implementation are important for helping things run more efficiently and smooth. If you ran into this same kind of problem again and didn't have Partitioning already setup, you would probably find it quicker and less overhead to insert the minority of rows you want to keep into a new table, drop the old table (which is rather immediate of a change), and then rename the new table to the old one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like an issue I've run into before (or some variation of it), but without access to your servers or the ability to reproduce it, I can't be sure.

If you have a lot of queries which select the minimum/maximum value from an indexed column in that table, they will normally be satisfied instantly by consulting the end points of the index.  But when many rows at the end have been deleted, it needs to walk back until it finds the extreme point which is still live.  This can take a while when you have so many deleted rows that need to be walked past.  Once the deleted tuples are "dead to all" (all transactions open at the time of the DELETE have gone away) you should be able to set hint bits on the tuples themselves and on the index entries ('microvacuum' or 'killed items' or 'index hint bits') which solve or at least ameliorate the problem, and then it should finally be completely resolved by vacuum which should remove not just the index entries, but also index pages which are full of nothing but dead entries.  But until all long-live transaction/snapshots go away, none of these mechanism will work, so make sure you don't have open transactions.

In summary, autovacuum isn't causing the problem.  Rather, it is trying to fix the problem and just hasn't finished yet, or has been frustrated by open snapshots.

In older version, the same thing can happen when doing cost estimates for mergejoins.  The planning process did the same kind of end-point probing, and suffered the same problem.  I think that that issue had been fixed by v14, though.

Comment: It's interesting how this part of the PostgreSQL engine differs from other database systems, specifically the way snapshot versioning and vacuuming function. I only recently came across an article that discussed the history of their transaction handling and how it influenced the way the engine was designed which resulted in both positives and negatives on the whole.

Comment: @J.D. you should probably link to an article if you are going to mention it

Comment: @user253751 It was probably about about 3-4 months ago when I read about it, so I'll have to do some digging. But this is a pretty good [RedGate article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/postgresql/uncovering-the-mysteries-of-postgresql-auto-vacuum/) that discusses the uniqueness of vacuuming due to the implementation of MVCC in PostgreSQL, as opposed to other commonplace database systems. I find it extra interesting because SQL Server also offers a form of MVCC (though not on by default) but it must be implemented differently because vacuuming isn't necessary with it.

Comment: In fact, there were many concurrent requests (load test) at about 1500 rps that were doing a massive query on that massive table, that among other things sorted by a column in a multi-column index. I would imagine that these transactions must have been closed, at least with some client timeout, but something else might have been blocking the autovacuum. Or maybe it just took a long time to do it's thing, during which ongoing requests worked extra hard and drove the CPU to 100% which didn't help to move things along. No way to check now, so I'll accept this as the answer.